# Which PHP file to add to my Path using WampServer (Win7/64)

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, composer-php

I've been reading up on TDD using PHP and i'm ready to install PHPUnit, however...

1. I'm on Win7/64 running WampServer
2. I'm reading all these PEAR/PHPUnit install nightmare stories which are making me very leery.
3. So I'm considering using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to install PHPUNit (to skip the whole PEAR thing, for now).
4. Either way, it seems that it's ***best to have PHP in the PATH***, which is **not** the case for default wampserver setup I suppose (since it's NOT already in my PATH)

I'm a bit confused about exactly which php file I should be adding to the PATH, as my directory (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10) has the following files:

1. php.exe
2. php-win.exe

I was planning on using number 1.

Finally, are there any other caveats that I should be aware of.

I'm using NetBeans (and SublimeText2 for front end stuff) and WampServer 2.2

Thanks!

sleeper

Comment: OK, so it seems I just add the directory (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10), not an individual file. Did so, rebooted then ran "php -v" and whalla! it's working! I will leave this open to see if anyone offers any pertinent info (gotcha's, best practices, etc.).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I Solved it. I  just add the directory (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10), not an individual file. See my comment.